# URI encoding in Python Requests package

Tags: python, python-requests, urlencode

I am using python requests package to get results from a API and the URL contains + sign in it. but when I use requests.get, the request is failing as the API is not able to understand + sign. how ever if I replace + sign with %2B (URI Encoding) the request is successful.

Is there way to encode these characters, so that I encode the URL while passing it to the requests package

```
Error: test user@gmail.com does not exist
API : https://example.com/test+user@gmail.com
```

Comment: Take a look at [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html). In particular, see `urlencode`, but it's a good idea to see what else that module has to offer.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use `requests.utils.quote` (which is just [a link](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/compat.py) to [`urllib.parse.quote`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)) to convert your text to url encoded format.

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.utils.quote('test+user@gmail.com')
'test%2Buser%40gmail.com'
```

Comment: This solution is answering the question but little bit not correct. `'https://example.com?callback_url=' + requests.utils.quote('https://callback.com')` will return `'https://example.com?callback_url=https%3A//callback.com'` (`//` didn't escaped). This happens because of default `safe='/'` argument. `requests.utils.quote(some_string, safe='')` will escape all specific symbols.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3+, one can URL-encode any string using the [`urllib.parse.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) (alternatively, you could use [`requests.utils.quote()`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/083aa67a0d3309ebe37eafbe7bfd96c235a019cf/requests/compat.py#L58), which is essentially using the same `quote()` function from `urllib.parse` module). This function is intended for quoting the path section of a URL, not the whole URL. It will essentially replace any special characters in a string using the `%xx` escape. In Python 2.x, the `quote()` function can be accessed directly from the `urllib` package, i.e., `urllib.quote()`.

**Note** that the `quote()` function considers `/` characters *safe* by default. Hence, in case you are passing another URL to the path section (or the query string) of the URL and would like  to encode `/` characters as well, you could do so by setting the `safe` parameter to `''`, i.e., an empty string.

### Example

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote 

base_url = 'https://example.com/'
path_param = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ultralytics/yolov5/master/data/images/zidane.jpg'
url = base_url + quote(path_param, safe='')
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.request.url)
```