# ampersand is being replaced with comma

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to do a rest call to jira and the jql is as below.

```
jql="Project" = "Test: Dev int: commons & Uig mat"
```

so when i do the rest call to jira, it is replacing the jql as below:

```
jql="Project" = "Test: Dev int: commons ',' Uig mat"
```

so, the & is being replaced with "," which is throwing an error as that project is not available in jira

I tried replacing the "," with &, it is again replacing it with "," while it is run.

```
import requests

url = "https://jira.com/login/rest/api/2/search"
querystring = {jql='working Project' = 'Test: Dev int: commons & Uig mat'}


headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

I want to pass in exact string to jira to process and do the query

Comment: As it stands your `querystring` code isn't valid python. If you have double-quotes in your string, consider making your outer set of quotes be single-quotes, so you don't have to escape the double-quotes inside.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy -- thanks for the reply, but that code was from postman after processing, so it is changing the actual jira api call to that. but now i directly did a api call, it is still same error.            {
    "errorMessages": [
        "Error in the JQL Query: The quoted string 'Test: Dev int: commons ' has not been completed.
    ],
    "errors": {}
}

Comment: You can't put ampersands and spaces into URLs. Maybe you need to [URI encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783078/uri-encoding-in-python-requests-package) them?

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried escaping the ampersand with the backslash character? (which may necessitate doing double-backslash to escape the backslash character itself)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy - I escaped it using \\ and \ but no luck, throws error.        {
    "errorMessages": [
        "Error in the JQL Query: The escape sequence has not been completed. The valid escape sequences are \\', \\\", \\t, \\n, \\r, \\\\, '\\ ' and \\uXXXX.],
    "errors": {}
}

Comment: Can you try putting the string in triple quotes and then see if it's working ? Example - """<your string here > """

Comment: i just replaced the & with %26 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced & with %26 and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Had a problem with Jira Jql query, solved with %26.
This is an example :

```
{
"key": "search?jql= project = \"SS\" AND \"Customer Request Type\" = \"Infinity %26 Website (SS)\" AND \"Infinity Customer ID\" ~ \"417761\""
}
```