# Api calling issue on salesforce

Tags: python, api, salesforce

I am calling salesforce api using two queries which I mentioned below. For first query I am getting 200 status code with response and for second query I am getting 400. I searched a lot on internet but didn't get anything..Am I missing something in that query??

First Query::

[https://abc-client.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=Select+id+from+Account+where+Name+like+'%Keysto%'+and+BillingPostalcode+=+'FY1](https://abc-client.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=Select+id+from+Account+where+Name+like+%27%Keysto%%27+and+BillingPostalcode+=+%27FY1) 3PB'

Output:: 200 status code

---

Second Query:: [https://abc-client.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=Select+id+from+Account+where+Name+like+'%R](https://abc-client.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q=Select+id+from+Account+where+Name+like+%27%R) Cart%'+and+BillingPostalcode+=+'PE23 5DW'

### Output:: 400 status code

Comment: URI encode the query in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783078/uri-encoding-in-python-requests-package

Comment: Have you tried to run both query in the query editor (in dev console) ? Just to check that Salesforce can process them internally.

Answer (score 0):

400 is usually a Bad Request Error that arises from incorrect URL.
Be sure to URI encode your query before appending to the URL.
In case of js, you can use

```
encodeURIComponent(your_query_string_here)
```

and use it as follows.

```
'https://abc-client.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/query?q='+encodeURIComponent(your_query_string_here)
```